# AttributeError on a test case without using print

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I am fairly new to Python/Django and I am self taught, so perhaps I am missing something fundamental here...

I am trying to write a test case for Model Form in Django. 
I create an instance of my form, which I can print to see how Django renders the form.

Using form.cleaned_data also works, returning the values of the form.

```
    bulk_image_form = BulkTestForm(data={'daisy': 3, 'dandelion': 0, 'tulips': 0, 'sunflowers': 1, 'roses': 0})
    test_form = bulk_image_form
    print(test_form)
    print(test_form.cleaned_data)
```

However, as soon as I remove the first print statement *(print(test_form))*, the test_form.cleaned_data no longer works. The console reads the following:

AttributeError: 'BulkTestForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Why would a print statement have an impact on accessing the attributes of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `is_valid()` before you can access `cleaned_data`.

```
test_form = bulk_image_form
test_form.is_valid()
print(test_form.cleaned_data)
```

When you print the form, the form is validated as as side effect, so you can access `cleaned_data` even though you haven’t explicitly called `is_valid()`.